# values in class destroyed when getting back to main function c++

Tags: c++, class, data-structures, destructor

I've got a problem in my code in C++. 
I have a class DataStructure that I'm using and and in particular, its method GetAllCreaturesByLevel defined as follow:

```
Class DataStructure;
StatusType DataStructure::GetAllCreaturesByLevel(int magiID, int **creatures, int *numOfCreatures);
```

This method receives pointers from the main function and gives back some statistics about the object it is working on.

To use this method from the main function, I call a function that will pass the pointers from the main function, cast the object from void* to DataStructure* and call its method GetAllCreaturesByLevel. This function is defined as follow :

```
 StatusType GetAllCreaturesByLevel(void *DS, int magiID, int **creatures, int *numOfCreatures){
     if((DS == NULL)||(creatures == NULL)||(magiID == 0)||(numOfCreatures == NULL)){
        return INVALID_INPUT;
      }
    return ((DataStructure*)DS)->GetAllCreaturesByLevel(magiID, creatures, numOfCreatures);
}
```

The code works perfectly while in this function. The problem is when coming back to the main: the pointers gives back the right values but all the data in the object are changed and turned to garbage values.

What can be the cause of this bug ?

Comment: which object is destroyed? the one of type `DatStructure` or the one of type `StatusType`?

Comment: The object destroyed is the DataStructure* one (passed as a void*). StatusType is only a enum giving some infos about what's the final issue of the function (success, failure, allocation_error). The bizarre thing is the Destructor don't seems to be used.

Comment: Why are you using void pointers and ** arrays in C++? If you're actually programming in C, you need to **pass by value, or deference those values** you wish to change. As it stands, this function is trying to change values out of scope of main, and the original garbage values are still there because they are never changed.

Answer (score 0):

In the method I was using :

```
 int *creaturesArray = new int[*numOfCreatures];
```

and to enter the values in the creatures array:

```
for(int i = 0; i < *numOfCreatures; i++) {
     creatures[i] = &creaturesArray[i];
}
```

The problem is in Assembly. In the return to the main from GetAllCreaturesByLevel, the stack is bigger than when coming into the function and thus DS isn't at the same place in the stack it was before. As result, the value put into DS isn't it's real value but one of the addresses in the creatures array.

The solution is :

```
 int *creatures = new int[*numOfCreatures];
```

and to return creatures as is, without using another array on the way.